# Tar through ssh - how add exclude in one line command from local pc

Tags: ssh, tar

```
ssh root@1.1.1.1 tar cvpf - /root/1 > /home/user/arc.tar.gz
```

need add

```
--exclude=/root/1/2
```

i try and not work:

```
ssh root@1.1.1.1 tar cvpf - /root/1 > /home/user/arc.tar.gz --exclude=/root/1/2
```

Comment: Can you say in what way your command did not work? Did you, for example, get any specific error messages?  What Unix is running on the remote system, and what implementation of `tar` does it have?

Comment: Please add a bit of context to your question.  Until then, it will be marked as Closed, although I see a very well written answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `tar` reports exactly what's going on. Since you are using `--exclude` can I assume that is the version you're using? If so, please read what it told you:

```
tar: The following options were used after non-option arguments.  These options are positional and affect only arguments that follow them.  Please, rearrange them properly.
tar: --exclude ‘/root/1/2’ has no effect
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

This error message should have been in your question as it's highly relevant.

The solution is to rearrange the arguments properly:

```
tar cvpf - --exclude=/root/1/2 /root/1 > /home/user/arc.tar.gz
```

I note that you're writing to a file that implies it contains gzip-compressed data but that actually does not (you don't tell `tar` to generate a compressed output stream):

```
file /home/user/arc.tar.gz
/home/user/arc.tar.gz: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

Here is the resulting corrected command in full:

```
ssh root@1.1.1.1 tar czvpf - --exclude=/root/1/2 /root/1 >/home/user/arc.tar.gz 

file /home/user/arc.tar.gz
/home/user/arc.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 …123456…
```